# Why does this function not return True and instead loop around?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [234. Palindrome Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/)

> Given the head of a singly linked list, return true if it is a
> palindrome or false otherwise.

My code worked for lists with an even amount of nodes. When I tried to change it with an `if` statement to advance one more node, the code started to loop. The code prints 'here' at the bottom but does not return True and instead loops and runs again.

There is an error with the `tail.next = None` line when it runs a second time.

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return True
        slow = fast = prev = head
        count = 0
        while fast and fast.next:
            prev = slow
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            count += 1

        if count % 2 == 1:
            prev = slow
            slow = slow.next
        
        curr = slow
        tail = curr
        start = prev
        while curr:
            next_node = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = next_node
        tail.next = None
        start.next = prev
        slow = fast = head
        for x in range(count):
            fast = fast.next
        while fast:
            if slow.val != fast.val:
                return False
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next
        print('here')
        return True
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the programming language.  Also, you say there is an error, but you don't tell us what the error is. Please add in the exact text of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- `if count % 2 == 1:` makes no sense. We can imagine there is a slight difference between a list with an even number of nodes and one with an odd number of nodes, but `count` does not represent the number of nodes in the list: it represents half the number of nodes in the list. And whether that count is odd or even has no relevant meaning.
- Related to the previous point, if the list has two nodes, then `count` will be one, and so you'll set `slow` to `None` by this `if` block. This will result in an exception when executing `tail.next = None` as `tail` is `None` at that moment.
- `start.next = prev` is a dangerous assignment. If the preceding `while` loop only makes one iteration, then `start == prev` and this assignment will create a loop. This happens if the previous point is resolved by removing `tail.next = None` to avoid the exception, and the input is a list with two nodes. The program will get into an infinite loop.

Some other remarks:

- It should not be necessary to keep a `count`. As explained above, it serves no purpose when wanting to know the parity of the list. And the loop that you have near the end, that is based on `count`, can be replaced by `fast = prev`, as just had just reversed the second half, and made `prev` the head of that second list.
- You wrote *"The code prints 'here' at the bottom but does not return True and instead loops and runs again."*. This is a misunderstanding. It *does* return, but LeetCode continues to run a second test case.

Here is a fix of your code:

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return True
        # Find center: no need for a counter
        slow = fast = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next

        # Reverse second half
        prev = None  # This is the way to ensure the reversed list ends with None
        while slow:
            next_node = slow.next
            slow.next = prev
            prev = slow
            slow = next_node

        # Compare halves, we can reuse `head`
        fast = prev  # No loop needed, we know where the second half starts
        while fast:
            if head.val != fast.val:
                return False
            head = head.next
            fast = fast.next
        return True
```